# How to reference ViewModels (in separate Web project) in an Interface in another project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, interface, controller

I'm creating an Interface for a controller which handles a variety of form submission methods, which all use specific ViewModels as parameters. My goal is to use Dependency Injection(DI) to pass the Interface into a different controller which needs to execute one of the methods from the Interface.

[image: Interface with broken reference to ViewModel param]

The Interface and Controller worked fine when the Interface was placed inside the Web project, however once I moved the Interface into the Interfaces project, the references to the ViewModels broke and I cannot figure out how to resolve them.

I was able to use this to instead directly call the method without going the DI route, however the rest of our site uses DI and I didn't want to break the pattern:

```
var controller = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<FormController>();
controller.SendForm(model);
```

I've tried:

- Adding the Web project as an assembly reference to the Interfaces project, however that would create a circular reference (as VS kindly let me know.)
- Intellisense, no recommendations.
- Adding a Using directive, but the Web project is not an available Namespace to select from

This is a ASP.NET MVC site on 4.6.1. The controller lives in the Controllers folder under the Web project. The new interface is in a separate Interfaces project in the same solution.

Comment: How about moving the View Models into its own project as well and then reference it both in the interface and the web project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the View Models into its own project and then reference it both in the interface and the web project.

Comment: Sounds like a little more work than I'd like to do, as I've have to add a using everywhere a ViewModel is referenced in the Web project then, right? But still a solid suggestion, I will mark as correct if that's the best solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why do you have to add a using statement where a ViewModel is referenced? Is your ViewModel is a POCO?

Comment: Yes, they are POCOs. If they were moved into a new project (with a new namespace) then I would have to add a Using directive to each file referencing a ViewModel in the original Web project. Not the end of the world but less than ideal as we have a good amount.

Comment: @webDevAndEverythingElse Well if introducing a using solves your problem then that is what you have to do? And how is this less than ideal?